# How to use on_click on a simple python plotly code

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to get started on event handling in plotly. The (more complex) examples I see on the [internet](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/doc/python/click-events.md) don't work for me.
Here is the simple code I wrote to get a first hook:

```
import plotly
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(1,1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2], y=[1,4]))
scatter = fig.data[0]

global TEST
TEST = "Was not called"

def saver(trace, points, selector):
    print('Hello')
    global TEST
    TEST = "Was called"  

scatter.on_click(saver)
fig.show()
print(TEST)
```

Clicking on the figure does not do anything. The TEST variable remains unchanged.

I am calling the code above from a Jupyter notebook.

Thank you

Comment: Try this:`f = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=[1,2], y=[1,4], mode='markers')]);scatter=f.data[0];#fig.show()`

Comment: Thank you.
I tried that but it did not work.
Note: the plot appears inline in the notebook, I am not sure if it should appear outline for events to work and how to do that.